# Disallow users below some amount of reputation to post questions

Tags: discussion

Most of the time when I see a user with 1 rep asking a question, this question is (to make it polite) not really good. Moreover some of the users are never even going to accept the answer.

Does it make sense to disallow users below some amount of reputation to post questions. This way we can be sure that user already familiar with the way how SO works and can behave appropriately.

I thought that suggestions like this already appeared here, but I was not able to find anything. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Just one question for you. Let's assume for a second, that you disallowed questioning from all new users (1 rep). Now, for submitting a question they need at least X rep. How do you suppose them to increase reputation? There are two basic ways: you can either ask good questions or give good answers. Now, you've just  vetoed one of these ways. Do you expect new users to _ANSWER_ other questions to gain some rep? (I've just imagined that picture...)

Comment: @Olter how about the easiest way - to edit other's posts? +2 rep for nothing? And what is wrong with trying to give answers?

Comment: As soon as you *force* people to *contribute something*, guess what happens: you'll get a bunch of random "contributions", regardless of any quality or value they may add. You're actually making the problem worse. Instead of just getting low-quality questions, we now get low-quality edits as well.

Comment: @deceze I agree with you. Some of the edits will be low quality. It is easy to reject them and nothing bad will happen. If user has to many bad edits - ban him and this is it. But the quality of questions will increase.

Comment: Sooo... instead of moderating questions and downvoting and eventually banning users we're supposed to moderate edits and reverse them and eventually ban users for it? Sorry, not seeing the advantage here...

Comment: @deceze I found moderating edits much easier than seeing and closing questions. Also bad questions distract good people from giving good answers, edits do not. I hope this sounds like an advantage?

Comment: Then the much more straight forward solution would be to establish a new-user-question-quality-review-queue. At least tackle the problem you're trying to solve head-on, instead of establishing rules which backhandedly try to address the problem but will cause lots of collateral damage.

Comment: So how exactly will you create your review-queue. Do not forget, you just assume that they will cause a lot of damage. The same way I assume that this can help. I am here for discussion.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? You want to stop low quality questions to be posted and you've singled out new 1-rep users as the most frequent perpetrators (which I agree with). You want those new users to somehow proof that they're ready to post good questions. Then how about keeping new questions by 1-rep users on hold in a review queue and require moderator approval before they're shown publicly. Or at least before they're bumped to the front page or something? Straight forward solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Of course, this will shift the problem insofar as a more narrow community of queue moderators now wields the power over new users, not the SO community at large anymore. So I'm not exactly a fan of that idea either. As I see it, any solution is going to cause problems. At least the system in place now is a very democratic and fair system, even if it's annoying to regulars. I don't know how this annoyance can be solved, but I don't think your suggestion as is is the solution.

Comment: @deceze You are right. I want to solve the problem with low quality questions which distract people from normal questions. Yes, idea of moderator approval sounds nice. Any idea can cause some problems, we just need to find one that caused smallest amount and solves the biggest. I respect your thoughts that my idea is not correct, but it does not make my idea really bad. Only trying it can give some results.

Comment: Let's say that I'm positive your suggestion would work, insofar as we'd basically be slamming the door in new people's faces. No more new question equals no more new low-quality questions. But as I said below, that's not what SO stands for. Do we really want to create an elitist community of people, instead of an open system?

Comment: @deceze if by elitism you mean spending few minutes editing 5 posts, than I think that it would be better to create it. But this is just my  opinion.

Comment: @SalvadorDali +1 for your question. But I think,users should be given chances to post questions regardless of their reputations. One can get reputation only by posting questions at first. If I edit some other posts and start earning my first reputation, then there is no use for me in SO.May be, the moderators can guide new users to ask questions clearly without compromising the quality.

Comment: *It is easy to reject them and nothing bad will happen.* - Considering how many Meta questions there are about bad edits getting through and good edits getting rejected, I'm not sure this is true.

Answer (score 12):

I'm voting No, because this would be terrifically unfair to new users who are perfectly able to form a decent question and have an actual problem that they need help with *now*. These new users would be forced to first provide a good answer or ten which are actually upvoted by somebody, which is often a near impossible proposition unless they're frequenting the site anyway, in which case they probably already have reputation. You're getting into a Catch-22 situation is which virtually no new user will ever be able to post new questions, unless they're really enthusiastic about SE and stick with it for a long time before ever attempting to post a question.

SE is not trying to be exclusionary; on the contrary, it's trying to be as open as possible.

Comment: This would be unfair who are perfectly able to ask good questions, but they would be actually able to answer some questions and to get few rep points to ask questions. Moreover it is kind of easy to edit some posts as well. By trying to be as open as possible there is literally millions of crappy questions every day, which distract from normal questions.

Comment: So imagine the following scenario: user is aware of SO by having stumbled across it via Google many times in the past, finding it a great resource. One day this user decides he has a problem worthy of an SO question. SO tells him he doesn't have enough reputation. User is forced to click around the site for 30 minutes or more to do *something* to gain reputation. I see two outcomes: the user gives up after a while and solves his problem by himself; the user posts some random crap or makes some random edits just to get over that magic hump. Nobody is really off any better in the end.

Comment: I see it a little bit differently. Some of the users will post crap (bad answers which will be downvoted, user get no rep and in the end he will be banned, or bad edits which will be rejected and user will be banned). What will we lose? Bad user, but we will have problems with rejecting his edits - really easy, bad answers - a little bit harder but also easy to remove. Some of the users will try and do something bad. He will learn how to do something and will be a nice contribution to SO.

Comment: This idea is also predicated on there being content in need of edits though. Let's assume we did go with your idea and basically forced users into editing stuff and every single post on SO would magically improve through that. At some point everything will be as optimal as could possibly be. What are new users supposed to edit then? You'll end up with entirely superfluous, useless edits for nothing. And that is the *ideal* scenario, which will never even happen. Instead content quality will probably go down rather than up first. You're just shifting the problem around, not solving it.

Comment: I see a problem, and looking how to fix it. May be this is not the right way to do it, but I see how thing got worse here. What can be edited - huge amount of things: wrong English usage, bad links (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php.net how many from these answers/questions can be helped with links formatting?), wrong formatting. These will not be the best edits, but they will be helpful. So I disagree with shifting around.

Comment: I think the most egregious formatting problems are already being solved pretty quickly right now without forcing anyone to do it. The more minor formatting problems remaining... I don't know whether new users would be in the best position to fix those. The same for correct English usage, you'd be excluding a whole host of people there. Basically, my issue is that you're raising the bar way too high with this requirement. People suddenly don't simply need to be able to form a decent question, they must now also be anal-retentive about formatting *and* speak English good. Too exclusionary, IMO.

Comment: in less than a minutes I have found kind of a lot of posts that are easy to improve without even being able to speak English. As I told this is not the best edits, but it is easy to do and will improve a little bit the quality of posts. Nothing exclusionary. Just a little bit of work before using help for free.

Answer (score 2):

Too many characters for a comment, so I'll write it down here.

First, I'm not sure, that editing is allowed to new users

> ( 1:create posts; Ask a question or contribute an answer).

But the primary point here is different: usually a newbie in some area can't answer anything. Imagine, that you are leaning a new programming language. How quickly would you be ready to answer a specified question on it? Usually, questions first, answers after. I know some people, who came here with a bag of knowledge, who started to answer immediately after registration, but most people come here to learn first.

Some people are good learners, some can become good learners.
Some people will stay code monkeys forever.

So, instead of posting bad questions, code monkeys will post bad answers and edits. Will this change anything? I doubt it. Just different work for moderators. They would see close votes on answers, instead of close votes on questions, that's the only difference.

If you see a bad question, shame its author into googling, but don't take away the possibility of asking questions. Perhaps, the author will change. <s>Perhaps not.</s> Believe in mankind.

Comment: I totally agree with that most new users will not be able to answer. But you do not need to be a programmer to edit questions. You do not even need to speak English properly. As I already told to deceze - you will find hundreds of post with badly formatted links or badly formatted code. It is not hard to improve them, and it can help to do something better. Believing in mankind is good, but I believe that laziness is changing the world. Check how many people are telling that the quality of SO is decreasing, so it disagres with belief in mankind.

Comment: *First, I'm not sure, that editing is allowed to new users* - There is no limit to editing. You don't even need to have an account to edit posts on the main site.